# CPT unsaved draft gives error 404 - when Post Formats support enabled

Tags: custom-post-types, 404-error, post-formats, draft

I've a plugin for Portfolio CPT (can be downloaded from here: http://bit.ly/1tEj5bC), using this plugin, every thing works fine. But when i edit any portfolio entry and click on 'Preview Changes' BEFORE saving the edited entry, instead of showing edited content, it gives me error 404.

The url which gives 404 error is something like this ...

```
http://www.example.com/portfolio/post-name/?preview=true&preview_id=192&preview_nonce=2d14ae4815&post_format=gallery
```

Now, if i remove `post_format=gallery` parameter from this URL, it shows the portfolio post.  So, If i remove post-format support in the plugin, it does not append this parameter when viewing the draft but i need this plugin to support post-formats.

How to resolve the issue?

**Update:** I've tested two more third party plugin for portfolio CPT, adding post formats support in those plugin also leads to same error. It means, most probably, there is nothing wrong with the plugin code.

JFYI, post formats support is being added by passing following args through `register_post_type()` ...

```
'supports'          => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'post-formats'),
```

Comment: Did you contact to the plugin author regarding your issue?

Comment: i'm the plugin author, but not sure if this is a bug in WordPress itself or there is any issue in the plugin code.